# What is the alternative to deprecated RACSignal buffer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Im trying to do concurrent loading with with reactive cocoa and my implementation uses buffer method, which is deprecated. How I can change it without losing much of clearness in code?

Input: array of loadings signals that sends "next" only once and completed/error

Desired result: follow the limit of of only 5 concurrent requests and send next only when batch of 5 requests loaded to do not update UI to frequent.

My implementation:

```
RACSignal *concurrentLoadingSignal = [[loadingsSignalsArray rac_sequence].signal flatten:5];
RACSignal *finalSignal = [[concurrentLoadingSignal buffer:5] map:^id(id loadingResults) {
                NSMutableArray *allResults = [NSMutableArray new];
                for (NSArray *result in loadingResults) {
                    [allResults addObjectsFromArray:result];
                }
                return allResults;
            }];
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in github [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/587) discussing deprecation of `-buffer:` method, this approach might work:

```
RACSignal* finalSignal = [[[[[concurrentLoadingSignal
                          take:5]
                          collect]
                          map:^id(NSArray* loadingResults) {
                              // do your thing
                          }]
                          repeat]
                          takeUntil:[concurrentLoadingSignal ignoreElements]];
```